# Can I sync folders from a fat32 partition with UbuntuOne?

Tags: 11.04, ubuntu-one

Can I sync folders from a fat32 partition with UbuntuOne in natty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your partition is likely mounted outside your home folder; Ubuntu One doesn't support syncing files that aren't in your home folder, as described at [Why not sync folders outside home with Ubuntu One?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51362/why-not-sync-folders-outside-home-with-ubuntu-one). That answer also has some discussion of syncing from other partitions and why you should be wary of it, so if you decide to mount your FAT partition in your home folder in order to make it syncable, please read that answer first to discover why that's potentially not a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have only to enable sync from the folders, like any other folder.

I remember you that the fat32 can't preserve some extended file attributes. But for "normal" data works great.

Comment: Thanx for answering but that doesn't work here. The options for enabling UbuntuOne sync isn't enabled.Maybe I've set the wrong rights?