# Files on external memory are not uploaded, why?

Tags: ubuntu-one

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why not sync folders outside home with Ubuntu One?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51362/why-not-sync-folders-outside-home-with-ubuntu-one)

I have many files on an external Iomega HDD 1Tera, but they are not uploaded so i need to copy them on the U1 folder on the pc to get them uploaded. Any help, please?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu One will only sync folders inside your home folder. The reason is that if you were syncing from removable devices and by some accident it was disconnected, it would seem as if all files were removed, and be deleted from the website and all your other devices.

If you really, really, really want to do this, on Ubuntu you can use a bind mount as explained here: [How do I sync an external drive using Ubuntu One?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53414/how-do-i-sync-an-external-drive-using-ubuntu-one)

Best regards