# How to add /var folder to Ubuntu One storage to sync?

Tags: ubuntu-one

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why not sync folders outside home with Ubuntu One?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51362/why-not-sync-folders-outside-home-with-ubuntu-one)

Ubuntu One allows only `/home` folders to sync. Why? I want to sync the `/var` folder too.

Comment: Why are you wanting to sync the /var folder? That doesn't inherently sound like something you'd want to or should be doing...

Comment: @eltommo: I have /var/www folder where I develop projects.

Comment: Could you just make a symbolic link to it in ubuntu one or does it ignore symbolic links? `ln -s /var/www /home/hey/www`

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu One only syncs folders that are in your `/home`, by design. Multiple reasons exist, including that Ubuntu One does not need super user rights, or to avoid messing with how programs are installed.